# What happens to the nitrous oxide in the whipped cream when it is on your food?

Tags: food-chemistry

Nitrous oxide is used to create whipped cream but there is no information available on what happens to that gas when you eat it in the cream.

Comment: Here's a related post: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/76505/why-does-whipped-cream-use-nitrous-oxide-instead-of-nitrogen-gas

Comment: From a personal medical point of view? Or what your body might do with it (more bio than chem)? What, specifically, are you asking about?